# how to parse POST request body within Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

is there a way to retrieve the body from a POST request in Logic App?

Sending the POST request:

[image: HTTP POST]

Parsing the response:

[image: Parse JSON]

This of course allows me to write the body from the actual HTTP response, but I'm looking for a way to log the body from the POST request.

Any ideas are much appreciated !

***UPDATED***

I was thinking about this approach as well but I haven't mentioned yet that I basically need to iterate over an array and for each iteration send an HTTP POST request.

So, I'm initializing the variable outside the for loop:

[image]

Inside the for loop, iterating over the `results` array:

[image]

But as I go trough my logic and finally arrive at the step where I would like to reference THAT variable to write it to a blob, I  can't select it:

[image]

Comment: … and if you scroll down or hit “see more”?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing's there, I can for example select 'Current item' but that's just the current object the loop is iterating over from the array ...

Answer (score 0):

You can always reference a variable using the expression tab.  In this case you would enter the following into the textbox on the expresison tab of the dynamic content modal:

`variables('Body_to_send_in_POST_request')`

Reference: [Reference guide to workflow expression functions in Azure Logic Apps and Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#variables)